# Abscissa is the tangent line for the function...

Tags: calculus

I have such a problem: Find the parameter $a$ for which the abscissa is the tangent line for the following function:

$$f(x)=a+9x-\frac{x^3}{3}$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Again the tag "algebraic geometry" is misused...

Comment: I've tried to find the equation of the tangent line and then....???

Comment: As a side comment the abscissa usually refers to the horizontal coordinate of a point on the $x$-axis. I think (but I am not native english speaker) that your formulation of the problem is (in english) not correct... in my understanding the abscissa cannot be a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $(c,0)$ a point of tangency:

$$a+9c-{c^3\over 3}=f(c)=0,$$
$$9-c^2=f'(c)=0.$$
And now, $c=$? and $a=$?.

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand:)

Comment: @user123499 It gives two solutions. From left to right, the function $f$ is decreasing (coming from $+\infty$) until it reaches a (low) horizontal tangent line. It then increases on a bounded interval until it reaches another (high) horizontal tangent, and finally $f$ decreases (towards $-\infty$) on the right-most interval. Depending on $a$, either the first (low) tangent or the last (high) one can be coincident with the abscissa axis.

Comment: @Jeppe, true. Edited.